# Different length of value from uuid_short function of mysql

Tags: mysql, uuid, amazon-rds

Hello guys i'm trying to use uuid_short function of mysql in the project. But there is an one problem.

When I run it localy it is returns 17 digits. But when i run it amazon rds it returns 19 digits. Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Amazon RDS has a different server ID than you.

Sure enough, 255 << 56 = 18374686479671623680 (20 digits)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short

```
The UUID_SHORT() return value is constructed this way:

  (server_id & 255) << 56
+ (server_startup_time_in_seconds << 24)
+ incremented_variable++;
```

Comment: Thanks it helps. I thought like that and changed my server id using set global and length didn't changed. So change it from my.ini and restarted mysql server and result is both are generating 19 digits. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. I'm curious as to why you need them to be the same length?

Comment: What i want is unique, random, fixed and short key. And found this function in mysql. But on first try my development and test server's result was different.
That's all :)